# 16.04: Powering off discrete graphics results in kernel panic

Tags: kernel, 16.04, vgaswitcheroo, amd-graphics

I am trying to disable my discrete GPU, as I don't need the extra power and I'd rather have a longer battery life. I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 with the `4.6.0-040600rc1-generic` kernel and `amdgpu` as driver.

I succeeded in powering the AMD GPU off using

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

but when rebooting/shutting off the system I am met with a kernel panic mentioning something a long the lines of:

BUG: Unable to handle kernel paging request at ...

I believe this has to do with the `amdgpu` driver, since the traceback mentions it multiple times.

Any ideas on how to disable the discrete GPU, without causing a kernel panic?